# What are pros and cons of loading scripts in JS code

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript there is a way to dynamically load other scripts in code. For me, as a developer with mostly Java background, this seems to be more natural and seems like a separation of concerns (code and its dependencies are in JS code while HTML is used only for markup).

But it seems that dynamically loading script in code is not widely used. The only advantage of declaring dependencies in HTML, that comes to my mind is possible speed-up of JavaScript loading. Are there any advantages? What are other pros and cons of loading scripts in JS code?

Comment: Have you had a look at yepnope - http://yepnopejs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic loading scripts is used quite often where it's useful, thus [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) exists.

Compared to Java, the big issue with loading JS dependencies on the fly is that every single one makes another HTTP request. And minimizing requests count is one of the primary concerns of frontend optimisation. This is why most of the time all of the Javascripts are bundled into a single file.

It takes a very large and seldom used Javascript dependency to make dynamic loading effective.

[EDIT] But, if you're looking for an explicit dependency system for Javascript, there are many. Ruby on Rails people use [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets), for example - you can [`require`](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-require-directive) one script from another, and all dependencies will be gathered into a single file for deployment (very much like JAR files).

Comment: Do you know about any measurements related to penalties of dynamic loading? JS files can be effectively cached, so this should be an issues only on the first load, am I right?

Comment: I know that most Javascript dependency management tools still bundle the scripts into one file for deployment. I added an example of such a tool in the answer. As your concern was with declaring JS dependencies in JS code, this should be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Loading the resources in script delays the loading of the resources until the script is executed (duh). It is considered a good practice to put javascript file references at the very end of the `body` tag, to prevent it from blocking other downloads like the markup itself and images. So loading them in will have the same effect.

CSS files are put in the `head` tag, because the browser needs the information as fast as possible to start layouting your website. Javascript files are not needed for layouting, since they very often rely on DOM manipulation and thus need to wait until the DOM is loaded in its entirety. Therefore, javascript files to the very end of `body`. There are some exceptions, but in general you can do it like that.

It is often not needed to link to any dependencies (or it should be not needed), since it is also considered good practice to minify and concat all javascript files to one big file and put a reference to that in your HTML. This reduces the number of HTTP connections needed to load your website (every "external" resource generates a new HTTP connection)